# Fullcalendar js - month value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

How to fetch the month value from fullcalendar.js so that I can use it in my backend code.

I am using this fullcalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends if you are trying to get the month value on start up or the month value of the current page of the calendar.  I'll explain both.  But if it's the month value on startup then you should look at the first comment below your question. The docs aren't super specific on how you implement that though (they have no examples) so I'll explain that one. Basically when you initialize full calendar you can put in options. In the [docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) all the links with grey circles to the left of them are options. The property of the JavaScript object that you use for the option is the name they use for the links in this case month.  The value's needed data type can be found by clicking on the link in this case it's an integer. (found [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/)) So the following would work when initializing the calendar with options.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    month: 0,
    events: '/myfeed.php'
})
```

So the month the calendar starts at in this case would be January because it's a zero based index of the months (1 would be February, 2 = March, etc...)

The thing is if you don't define it on start up then it will default to the current month which you could get by creating a new date object and using the getMonth method of that date object, or you could just do the built in getDate function which will get the date of the current page your on on the calendar, but I'll explain that one later. So here is the date object method for just getting the current month.

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
```

Month again will be a zero based index of the months (0 being January, etc...)

If you are trying to get month that you are currently paged on use the [getDate function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/getDate/).

```
var d = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var month = d.getMonth()
```

Make sure that where #calendar is you put in the selector you used to initialize full calendar.

The variable month will yet again come out to be a zero based index of the months so 0 is January, 1 Feb., etc...

Hope this helped, and sorry if I'm a little too descriptive. I were just new to front end dev. or if you were confused (like I was at times) by the lack of examples on some parts of the documentation. :)

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to give a detailed explanation when the question was somewhat vague :)

Comment: @user3109801 Hey no problem. Good luck on your calendar application.